# Android Room Persistent library update not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm using `room` in my new Android app, and I'm trying to update an a model object's property at runtime, but it doesn't seem to get saved.

Entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "sessions")
data class Session(@ColumnInfo(name="id") @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Int = 0,
                   @ColumnInfo(name="date") var date: Date,
                   @ColumnInfo(name="repetitions_completed") var repetitionsCompleted: Int,
                    @ColumnInfo(name="squeeze_time_per_rep") var squeezeTimePerRep: Int,
                    @ColumnInfo(name="finishing_repetitions_completed") var finishingRepetitionsCompleted: Int,
                    @ColumnInfo(name="finishing_squeeze_time_per_rep") var finishingSqueezeTimePerRep: Int)
```

In my app I'm using it like this

```
session = Session(0,date,0,slowSeconds,0,quickSeconds)
sessionDao.insertAll(sessionDB)

...
session.repetitionsCompleted = totalSlowReps
session.finishingRepetitionsCompleted = totalQuickReps
sessionDao.updateSessions(session)
```

The problem is that session's property values like `repetitionsCompleted` and `finishingRepetitionsCompleted` doesn't seem to be saved, and it always remain 0 when I restart the app. `updateSessions` also returns `0`

Here is the code for the Dao

```
@Dao
interface SessionDao {

    // https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#query-params

    @Query("SELECT * FROM sessions")
    fun getAll(): List<Session>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE date BETWEEN :from AND :to")
    fun getSessionsBetween(from: Date, to: Date): List<Session>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM sessions ORDER BY date LIMIT 1")
    fun getOldestSession(): List<Session>

    @Update
    fun updateSessions(vararg sessions: Session) : Int

    @Insert
    fun insertAll(vararg sessions: Session)

}
```

What's weirder is that update seems to work in my unit test, but not in the actual app code.

I don't know if this affects things, but I'm running this in a service.

Comment: Do you use background thread for call dao functions?

Comment: Hey no, I didn't

Comment: I have allow `allowMainThreadQueries().build()` when I init my database

Comment: ok then. I supposed if you use another thread it can be stopped earlier than data were saved. Now it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, the problem was that when I created the `session` object, object is returned with an `id` set to 0 rather than its autoGenerate primary key, so what I did was alter the `insert` to return it's inserted id

```
@Insert
fun insertAll(vararg sessions: Session) : List<Long>
```

When I create my session, I manually reassign its ID

```
sessionDB = Session(0,date,0,slowSeconds,0,quickSeconds)
val insertID = sessionDao.insertAll(sessionDB).first().toInt()
sessionDB.id = insertID
```

Comment: I hope you will forgive me for necroing, but I need to ask: how did you manage creating a `Session` object for updating the DB? I've stumbled upon this issue myself. I have concocted this ugly, ugly workaround: I have to query the DB using the foreign keys of the row I want to update to get its ID, and then set the ID on the object I'll pass to the DAO for performing the update. It's literally gross and I'm looking for a better way.

Answer (score 1):

maybe it sounds a little stupid but it fixed my issue. I guess all of you are familiar with the `OnConflictStrategy`. it's making sense to set strategy for insert. but [google](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Update#onConflict()) need this strategy for `@Update` as well as the default strategy is ABORT.

> @return How to handle conflicts. Defaults to {@link OnConflictStrategy#ABORT}.

so the solution would be.

```
@Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're not sending the class id.

the value `@PrimaryKey` of the `@Entity` Class